# How can I remove duplicates from a list in Scala with pattern matching?

Tags: scala, list, recursion, pattern-matching

As homework i have to write a function that will remove duplicates from a list. It should be recursive and with pattern matching. I am not allowed to use list functions like head,tail,contains,etc... .
For sorted lists i came up with this solution:

```
def remove(u:List[Int]):List[Int] = {
  u match { case Nil => u
  case hd::hd2::tl => if(hd == hd2) remove(hd2::tl) else hd :: remove(hd2::tl)
  case hd::tl => hd :: remove(tl)
  }
}
```

How can i do it for unsorted lists?

Comment: Does the order of the elements have to be the same as in the original list?

Comment: This is an example for an unsorted list. List(1,2,3,1,3,3))== List(2, 1, 3).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I won't do your homework for you, but hope, this will help.

1. You want to make your function *tail-recursive*. That means that the recursive call appears in the very last position of the function, so that the jvm can clear up the previous call from the stack before invoking it (it makes it execute very much like a loop, without requiring additional space on stack). In your original solution it is statements like this, that make it not tail-recursive: `hd :: remove(tl)`: you have to invoke the recursive call, and *then* prepend `hd` to its result. The *then* part breaks the idea of tail recursion, because jvm has to remember on stack the place to return to after the recursive call is finished.

This is typically avoided by carrying the final result of the function through the recursion as an argument:

```
  def remove(u: List[Int], result: List[Int] = Nil): List[Int] = u match {
     case Nil => result
     case a :: b :: tail if a == b => remove(b :: tail, result)
     case head :: tail => remove(tail, head :: result) 
  }
```

(Note, that both recursive invocations here are in the tail position - there is nothing left to do after the call returns, so the previous entry can be cleared from the stack prior to invoking the recursion).

2. You need another recursive function - `contains` -  that tells whether a given element is contained in a list. Once you have that, just replace the second  `case` clause above with something like

   ```
   case head :: tail if contains(head, result) => remove(tail, result)
   ```

and your job is done!

3. If you want to preserve the original order of elements of the list, you will need to `reverse` it afterwards (replace `case Nil => result` with `case Nil => result.reverse`) ... If you are not allowed to use `.reverse` here too, that's going to be another nice exercise for you. How do you reverse a list (tail-)recursively?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably go about sorting the list firstly so that we can apply the O(n) complexity pattern matching method but in order to keep the order you will need to index the list so that you can recover the order later, this can be done with the `zipWithIndex` method. And also since the data type changes from `List[Int]` to `List[(Int, Int)]`, you will need to define another recursive remove function inside the original one:

```
def remove(u: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    val sortedU = u.zipWithIndex.sortBy{ case (x, y) => x}
    def removeRec(su: List[(Int, Int)]): List[(Int, Int)] = {
        su match {
            case Nil => su
            case hd :: Nil => su
            case hd :: hd2 :: tail => {
                if (hd._1 == hd2._1) removeRec(hd2 :: tail)
                else hd :: removeRec(hd2 :: tail)
            }
        }
    }
    removeRec(sortedU).sortBy{case (x, y) => y}.map{ case (x, y) => x}
}

val lst = List(1,2,3,1,3,3)

remove(lst)
// res51: List[Int] = List(2, 1, 3)
```

Note: This follows OP's pattern and is not tail-recursive. And if you want a tail recursive version, you can follow @Dima's nice explanation.

Comment: gotta have to implement sortBy (recursively? ;)) as well I am afraid :/
Because, if you can do `.sortBy`, by in the world would you not be able to just do `.distinct` in the first place??? Or, at least, throw things into a `Set`?

Comment: Well I guess so. But also keep in mind this is an exercise and probably the purpose of this exercise is to get students familiar with pattern matching? Or learn some other functions other than `.distinct()`? It eventually depends. Implementing the `.sortBy` is a little bit overkill. :(

Comment: If the OP can't use head. tail, contains,. there's no way zipWithindex and sortBy are permitted! I don't think this is a useful answer